# Select results from specified year

Tags: mysql

I want the below query to only select results from a particular year. The eventID relates to an events table within which the event date is located.

championshipLeaderboard Table

```
 ------------------------------------
 | ID | eventID | playerId | points |
 ------------------------------------
```

events Table

```
 ------------------
 | eventID | date |
 ------------------
```

I'm having trouble on where to place the inner join so i can reference the events date correctly

```
SELECT playerId, SUM(points) top5
FROM
 ( SELECT x.*
        , CASE WHEN @prev = playerId THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
        , @prev:=playerId
     FROM championshipLeaderboard x
        , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars ORDER BY playerId,points
DESC) a
    WHERE i<=5 AND playerId = 1 AND YEAR(events.date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    GROUP BY playerId
    ORDER BY top5 DESC
```

See DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56ApCUAW6QFJ7vNiyLQqaF/1)

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+ by any chance?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: please share table data and expected result set.Instead of sharing the query to modify make that as tried query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion (see comments) i came up with this:

```
SELECT top5.playerId, SUM(top5.points) AS sumOfPoints
FROM (
    SELECT playerId, points
    FROM championshipLeaderboard
    INNER JOIN events ON championshipLeaderboard.eventID = events.eventID
    WHERE playerId = 1
    AND YEAR(events.date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    ORDER BY points DESC
    LIMIT 5
 ) AS top5
 GROUP BY top5.playerId
```

See also: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56ApCUAW6QFJ7vNiyLQqaF/5

Comment: I need the sum of the top 5 points totals for each player out of a maximum of 12

Comment: I am sorry, but i dont get what you want here. You have points and events. You want to see the top five events for each player summed up and then see the result limited to 12 rows? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Each player plays 12 events a year and gets allocated points depending on finishing position. The top 5 points are summed. This code does it correctly, but now I need to be able to select the result depending on the year the events are played

Comment: If you want to be able to run the above select for different years, just replace CURDATE() with whatever year you need.

Comment: I've added fiddle into my question now......so basically when we get to a new season next year i need to be able to specify the year the events were played so i can use in the archive section of my website

Comment: I added another snipped for you to be able to specify the year ('2019' in this case)

Comment: That works for the query you have posted, but that is not what is wanted, see fiddle

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56ApCUAW6QFJ7vNiyLQqaF/2 ???

Comment: This is what Rakim put down below......problem with this is the top5 returns 74 and it should be 61

Comment: Could you tell me which of the results of this select are NOT to beconsidered for the sum: ```SELECT playerId, events.eventId, year(events.date), events.date, points
    FROM championshipLeaderboard
    INNER JOIN events ON championshipLeaderboard.eventID = events.eventID
    WHERE playerId = 1 ``` ??? See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56ApCUAW6QFJ7vNiyLQqaF/4

Comment: The ONLY points to be summed are the top 5 highest values. So the rows where  the points are 4,0,3,0,0,6 should NOT be considered.

Comment: I edited the post. Hope this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join with `1=1`

```
    SELECT playerId, SUM(points) top5
FROM
 ( SELECT x.*
        , CASE WHEN @prev = playerId THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
        , @prev:=playerId
     FROM championshipLeaderboard x
     INNER JOIN events y ON x.event_id = y.event_id
     INNER JOIN (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars ON 1=1
     WHERE YEAR(y.date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
     ORDER BY playerId,points DESC
 ) a
    WHERE i<=5 AND playerId = 1  
    GROUP BY playerId
    ORDER BY top5 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Rakim, I've added a DB fiddle now, when i use your answer the calculation for top5 is wrong?